# how to make good rust

Tags: texturing

So I'm trying to do a sword for a scene: [image: I know the mapping issues on the edges. I'll handle it.]

It's set in a forest, in which the sword has been exposed to the elements and is starting to rust. I'm trying to not have too little corrosion, but also not have so much that it becomes gaudy or unrecognizable. I've found it rather tricky trying to strike that balance.

Then there comes the trouble of making the rust itself look convincing. I've been operating mostly off of the methods found in Andrew Price's Blender Guru rust tutorial.

I also mapped the smaller specs by running a bare metal texture through a color ramp.

In addition, I've tried tinting the whole blade texture a slight rust-color- though I'm not certain about that working.

The details are in the nodes (for the blade only, since I don't have the permissions for more pics.

Blade material: [image]

Comment: Could you be more precise about what exactly does not satisfy you in this material set up? If your aiming for a realistic scene, a diffuse-based shader with bump map for rust it's already good start in my opinion. If the rust is wet, you should introduce some glossiness, if the rust has been scratched, you should have less bump map, and so on...it depends. Maybe you should add some references (you can post links in the comment section), try to see how it looks with the whole scene or visit http://www.blendswap.com

Comment: that could help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37oBqhjDtBI. Concerning your nodes, I think it is hard to understand without knowing the textures you used.

Comment: To the first reply, I'm concerned from a perspective more artistic than technical; regarding how the amount of rust I've already painted conveys the time in which the metal has been exposed, and, if so, where and how to balance said rust with lighter colors of corrosion across the rest of the material (similar to how Andrew Price painted streaks in the aforementioned tutorial). As for the second, I used the "Grunge" texture found in the Blender Guru tutorial for the rust. To map the smaller bits, I used the seamless metal texture found here: http://www.textures.com/download/metalbare0234/57525